# Formula in picklist

Tags: formula, picklist

I want to create a field (say `Type__c`) where I can have an auto-generated picklist depending upon another custom field (say `Book__c`). This picklist will have a list of values (say A, B, C and D). My requirement is if in a record, `Book__c` has F, `Type__c` should have no data, but if `Book__c` has A, B C or D, `Type__c` should be updated with the value. Is it achievable from object and field level. Field type of this new field can be changed. Its not specific to picklist.

Comment: Create two picklist `book__c` and `type__c` and make create a Field dependencies on it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Field Dependency](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&language=en_US&type=0) for this. This would mean upon Change of the first picklist, your chosen value will filter the possible values for the second picklist. If you have both picklists created on the object, within the **Custom Fields & Relationships** choose **Field Dependencies** and create something similar to the following.

[image]

On the record, if you change the value of the PickList2, PickList1 options will be filtered.

[image]

You could also consider designing a [Workflow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_examples.htm&language=en&type=0) to do this if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the Book__c is a text field. I cannot change the field type of Book__c

Comment: Oh, your question states field type can be changed. A Workflow should do the trick for you then.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I create a workflow, how will I call this workflow in angular. we are using angular for front-end and have written a query where I need to call this newly created field/workflow in WHERE clause.